# YII2: identical elements in different activeform forms and their IDs

Tags: yii2, activemodel

I am building a project with YII2(a dating site). I have several "form models", i mean models that are used to create forms with activeform. In some forms/models i have identical fields, for example "gender" and "location" fields present in "registration" page and in "profile" page. Only some fields are identical, others are different so i can't use the same model for different pages/forms.

Now, the problem is that when i use different models for creating activerecord forms the IDs and CSS classes for the fields are also different.

For example, i have a model called 'SignupForm' and a model called 'EditProfileForm'. In view(template) i have a code like that

```
<?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(['id' => 'form']); ?>
<?= $form->field($model, 'test_field') ?>
<?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>
```

If i execute this code for different models i get different fields names(IDs):
"editprofileform-test_field" ID for "EditProfileForm" model
and
"signupform-test_field" ID for "SignupForm" model.

Why does it metter? Because i want to apply the same CSS styles and JavaScript handlers for identical elements. Is there a way to make IDs and CSS classes the same for activeforms generated using different models?

**EDITED**

One solution(posted by @marche) is to add ID parameter to text field

```
<?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(['id' => 'form']); ?>
<?= $form->field($model, 'test_field')->textInput([
    'class' => 'some-css-class',
    'id' => 'my-id',
]) ?>
<?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>
```

It works for text inputs but i also have AutoComplete widget

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'city')->widget(\yii\jui\AutoComplete::classname(), [

    'clientOptions' =>[
        'source' => new JsExpression("function( request, response ) {
          $.getJSON('/my-script?country='+country_id, {
            term: request.term 
          }, response );
        }
    ")
    ],
],['id'=>'my-test-id']) ?>
```

As you see i tried adding ID parameters to AutoComplete and it doesn't work. Please advise me how to assign ID parameter to AutoComplete widget.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a class to each field or specify their id>

```
<?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(['id' => 'form']); ?>
<?= $form->field($model, 'test_field')->textInput([
    'class' => 'some-css-class',
    'id' => 'my-id',
]) ?>
<?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>
```

If you add the class, then you can reuse them later on or use them when you want to use the same styles with 2+ elements. Otherwise, you define the id, so the framework will not auto-generate it.

**Edit**

For widgets you need to add the id or class inside options like the following:

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'city')->widget(\yii\jui\AutoComplete::classname(), [
    'options' => [
        'id' => 'my-test-id',
        'class' => 'my-css-class',
    ],
    'clientOptions' => [
        'source' => new JsExpression("function( request, response ) {
            $.getJSON('/my-script?country='+country_id, {
                term: request.term 
            }, response );
        }
    ")
    ],
]) ?>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It works for text field but i can't make it work for AutoComplete widget fields. Please see edited question

Comment: Edited my response.

Answer (score 1):

You  can do the same with autocomplete widget   eg: (for class you should use options)

```
echo AutoComplete::widget([
   'name' => 'country',
   'clientOptions' => [
    'source' => ['USA', 'RUS'],
   ],
   'id' = 'your_id_name'
   'options' =[ 'class' => 'your_class'],
]);
```

Comment: Your answer is correct but it is not possible to accept 2 answers. so i accepted the first one. Sorry.